# Error adding angular material for angular 6

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I'm really new to angular, and I'm learning angular 6
but I can't add a component like said by Getting Started page via

```
ng add component heroes
```

and something wrong happen, the error is:

```html
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"dryRun":false,"inlineStyle":false,"
inlineTemplate":false,"changeDetection":"Default","styleext":"css","spec":true,"flat":false
,"skipImport":false,"export":false}
Errors:

  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun).
```

when I googled it someone said it can be fixed by adding angular material, so I begin installing angular material, but My application error
this is the console log:

```html
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [ERROR ->][attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : "): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [ERROR ->][mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar "): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [ERROR ->][mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar "): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [ERROR ->][opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-li"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@7:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [ERROR ->][opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-li"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@7:4
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@5:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
"): ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@1:2, Directive MatSidenav
Parser Error: Unexpected token '?' at column 20 in [isHandset$ | async ? 'over' : 'side'] in ng:///AppModule/MyMenuComponent.html@6:4 ("<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  [ERROR ->]<mat-sidenav
   compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:22709)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:22696)
    at compiler.js:22639
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:22639)
    at compiler.js:22549
    at Object.then (compiler.js:206)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:215
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse @ compiler.js:14702
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate @ compiler.js:22709
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate @ compiler.js:22696
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:22639
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents @ compiler.js:22639
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:22549
then @ compiler.js:206
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:22548
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:22508
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:4790
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:81
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:43
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:30
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
contentScript.js:86 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
getIp @ contentScript.js:86
countData @ contentScript.js:91
(anonymous) @ contentScript.js:188
```

please help me guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you try to generate a new component,
with add, you can add libraries to your dependencies-(package.json).
try
"ng generate component [component name]"
(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-component).

Did you install angular/cli?
to use ng generate component you need angular/cli.
https://cli.angular.io/

anyway you can watch this "Angular Material Introduction & Setup" video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u679SQsfRVM

Comment: ok thank you, it was really my fault
i use the wrong command
so now I reinstall my angular after deletd it feom appdata folder and it works

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong, But first if you are only learning with angular there is no need to use angular material this idea is misleading.

**Ng Add**

> Another new CLI command `ng add <package>` makes adding new capabilities
>   to your project easy. ng add will use your package manager to download
>   new dependencies and invoke an installation script (implemented as a
>   schematic) which can update your project with configuration changes,
>   add additional dependencies (e.g. polyfills), or scaffold
>   package-specific initialization code.

**ng add** command is only for dependency management, check [this](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4) out.

If you are trying to genererate a component follow this:

```
ng generate component my-new-component
ng g component my-new-component # using the alias
```

Learn the basic of angular-cli before diving or atleast complete the **tour-of-heroes** tutorial from [angular.io](https://angular.io/).

For complete angular-cli command usage from the doc, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Answer (score 0):

```
Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(dryRun).
```

This error isn't a material error.

This means that in your `angular.json` file you have "dryRun" as a property, which is not supported. By the looks of it its
The "dryRun" property allows you to see what would happen when you do ng g  without actually editing files.

For example: `ng g c ops-components/dividers --project ops-lib --dryRun`

[image]

Remove the `dryRun` property.